# vs2017 native code debugging exception calling unmanaged code

Tags: vb.net, debugging, unmanaged

I'm calling a properly declared unmanaged C++ DLL from VB.NET as so:

```
input = 1 ' line 1
ret = myclass.ouch(input) ' line 2
ret = ret + 1 ' line 3
```

This works without a problem and the output is as expected.
I then wanted to debug my code. I set a BP at line 1 and step over (F10) to line 3. This again worked without a problem.
I then enabled "native code debugging" and did the same thing again. However this doesn't work anymore. As soon as I hit F10 (step over) on line 2, an exception is thrown in ntdll.dll (access violation writing location 0x).

Eventually I was hoping to be able to single step into the unmanaged function using F11 (step into), that also doesn't work with the same exception. However I'm very confused as why step over doesn't work either.

Also I was trying to set a BP inside the DLL code, however I can't do that because apparently "no symbols have been loaded for this document". That is another thing I don't understand, as the DLL is compiled with full debug on and it's properly included as a project in the solution.

Is there anybody who has an idea what the problem could be? Keep in mind, executing the code normal, without debug stepping over, works fine.

Comment: I was able to get the symbols for my DLL loaded. I can now set BP inside the DLL and all that works fine. The only mystery left is the debug step from managed to unmanaged which results in an exception. So far my workaround is to set BP inside the DLL when needed. That's better than nothing.

Comment: It is not possible to single-step from managed code into unmanaged code.  Unmanaged code requires a different debugging engine, the mode switch can only occur at a breakpoint.  In addition, you typically need the Tools > Options > Debugging > General > "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" checkbox ticked.  No fantastic explanations for a null pointer exception however.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I didn't know that this is not possible.